# WCF Activation for MSMQ where the service (.svc) is on the root

Tags: wcf, msmq, .net-4.5, was, netmsmqbinding

VS 2012/.NET4.5, Windows 8/IIS8 and 64 bit

Using WCF Service application, all the documentation that I've seen so far in naming my MSMQ queue to match the service name assume the fact that I am using an application or a virtual directory underneath the IIS website.

This is quoted from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789042.aspx

> The application being activated must match (longest match) the prefix
>   of the queue name.
>
> For example, a queue name is:
>   msmqWebHost/orderProcessing/service.svc. If Application 1 has a
>   virtual directory /msmqWebHost/orderProcessing with a service.svc
>   under it, and Application 2 has a virtual directory /msmqWebHost with
>   an orderProcessing.svc under it, Application 1 is activated. If
>   Application 1 is deleted, Application 2 is activated.

Also, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx

> However when you are hosting your MSMQ-enabled service in IIS 7 WAS,
>   the queue name must match the URI of your service's .svc file. In this
>   example we'll be hosting the service in an application called
>   MsmqService with an .svc file called MsmqService.svc, so the queue
>   must be called MsmqService/MsmqService.svc. Queues used for WCF
>   services should always be private

And, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx

> It's important to note that the activation of MSMQ endpoints only
>   works correctly if the queue has the same name as the .svc file (minus
>   the machine name). That means that if your service endpoint is
>   /server/app/service.svc, the queue name must be app/service.svc.

MyService.svc file is directly under the root of my IIS website (which is using a .NET 4 pool in integrated mode), so I did the following:

1. Creating a private transactional queue called MyService.svc and giving Network Services full control (for testing).
2. Setting my web.config endpoint: address="net.msmq://localhost/private/MyService.svc"
3. I was able to push a message to the queue using a client test application using the address in (2).
4. I added MSMQ protocol support to the website by executing the following:
   `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set site "MyWebsite" /+bindings.[protocol='net.msmq',bindingInformation='localhost']` (and checked that it added the support properly)
5. From my website advanced settings I have `http,net.tcp,net.msmq` In `Enabled Protocols`
6. I double checked that "Net.Msmq Listener Adapter", which is responsible for activating the service when a message arrives, is running and I restarted it.
7. My `web.config`:

```xml
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
      <add binding="netMsmqBinding" scheme="net.msmq" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="MsmqBinding_IMyService" exactlyOnce="true"
            receiveErrorHandling="Move">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="CompanyName.Service.MyService">
        <endpoint name="MyService"
          address="net.msmq://localhost/private/MyService.svc"
          bindingConfiguration="MsmqBinding_IMyService"
          binding="netMsmqBinding" contract="IMyService" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My service is not getting activated with the arrival of new messages to the queue and the messages stay in the queue. Is that because I am not using an application or a virtual directory or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is sorted by creating an application within the default website and modifying the configuration to fit the new path.